# Using the rbinom function in R in a matrix

Tags: r, for-loop, nested, evolutionary-algorithm

Preface:  I am fairly novice at using R, I've used SAS my entire adult life and am not used to working with matrices either.

I am currently working on a project for an evolutionary biology class that requires running the rbinom function through a nested loop over a matrix. 
The probability in the first row is set to 0.1 but then the value in subsequent rows must use the probability from the previous row. I cannot figure out how to reference the value in the previous row. My code is below, if anybody knows the syntax for this I would greatly appreciate it! Currently I have it set to i-1 but I know that's not right.

```
#equation = rbinom(1,2*N,p) / (2*N)

p<-0.1
N<-10
T<-5 #number generations
L<-3 #number independent SNP's
alleles<-matrix(nrow=T,ncol=L) #initialize a matrix of allele frequencies 
each generation
alleles[1,]<-p #initialize first row to equal p

for (j in 1:ncol(alleles)) {
      for (i in 2:nrow(alleles)) {
        alleles[i,j]<-(rbinom(1,(2*N),(i-1))/(2*N))
      }
} 
alleles
```

Comment: Not sure what your target outcome is. Note that "T" stands for TRUE in R, use my_T or so instead. And maybe (because I could not figure your wanted result out) replace in the inner loop: `alleles[i,j] <- (rbinom(1,(2*N), alleles[i-1, j])/(2*N))`?

Comment: Yes that worked perfectly! I work with data tables in SAS mostly so the matrix stuff in R throws me for a loop (pun intended)